# How to solve integral $1/(x\cdot \cos(x))$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I'm trying to solve an integral but I'm getting stuck whole the time.

$$\int\frac{2 \sin x}{x^2\cos^2 x}dx$$

I'm not sure if it's totally correct but I've been able to "simplify" the integral to:

$$\frac{-2\sin x}{x\cos^2x}+ 2 \int\frac{1}{x\cos x}dx + 2 \int\frac{1}{x\cos^5x}dx -  2 \int\frac{1}{x\cos^3 x}dx$$

So how can I solve either of those integrals? I've tried to put it in online integral calculators but they can't solve it. Is there a primitive function?

Comment: Since the integrand is continuous in its domain, an antiderivative exists. But it's likely not an elementary function.

Comment: Please do not rollback your question. The original version has lots of useful context which is useful for people trying to answer.